# Simplify pytorch einsum

Tags: python, pytorch, linear-algebra, numpy-einsum

Consider the following pytorch snippet:

```
X = torch.einsum("rij, sij -> rs", A, A)
Y = torch.einsum("rij, sij -> rs", B, B)
Z = torch.einsum("rij, sij -> rs", C, C)
torch.einsum("ij, ij, ij -> ", X, Y, Z)
```

which performs the following summation

[image]

Is it possible to formulate this in a more succinct (that is more vectorised/optimal) way? (e.g. using the fact that X, Y, Z are symmetric matrices)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it more succinct but I don’t see much room for actual performance optimisation:

```py
X = torch.einsum("rij, sij", A, A)
Y = torch.einsum("rij, sij", B, B)
Z = torch.einsum("rij, sij", C, C)
torch.einsum("ij, ij, ij", X, Y, Z)
```